# Can I use DebuggerDisplay info in Unit Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, vs-unit-testing-framework, debuggerdisplay

Something like:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Id=7, Name=John", someClass.DebuggerInfo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of your `SomeClass` to compare Id and Name properties:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        SomeClass other = obj as SomeClass;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return other.Id == Id && other.Name == Name;
    }

    // GetHashCode implementation
}
```

Asserting will look like:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expectedObject, someClass);
```

If you don't want or can't change `SomeClass` implementation, then you can create method which will do assertion:

```
public void AssertAreEqual(SomeClass expected, SomeClass actual)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Id, actual.Id);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Name, actual.Name);
}
```

Evaluating debugger display string is not simple task, because `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` contains only format string, which is used to evaluate string representation of object in debugger. That string besides simple property names can also contain expressions and method calls. You can evaluate debugger display value with help of Roslyn compiler, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989725/470005). But I don't think that usage of debugger metadata is a good way to check for objects equality.

Comment: You see, its an external class that has this attribute set, so I can't modify it. And I don't want override it only for test purpose.

Comment: Ofc, I can collect those property values myself, but isn't it convenient to use pseudo-code I provided? )

Comment: @dbardakov it's not that simple to evaluate format string from debugger display attribute on some object. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942258/any-code-that-duplicates-how-the-debuggerdisplayattribute-generates-the-resultin) is solution which uses [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn) compiler for that. I'd go with some object comparer method instead